# After Windows 10 Creators Update, Remote Desktop opens in wrong window

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-10-v1703

Prior to the update, I could move the remote desktop would open in the monitor where I clicked the Connect button. So if I wanted my remote desktop on the primary monitor, I would just move the app to that monitor and click connect. The same would work for my secondary monitor.

Now, post creators update (version 15063), it doesn't matter where I move the application, it always opens on my higher resolution display. I've tried changing which monitor is my primary, but it still acts the same way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have fixed this problem:

1. Start out with absolutely no RDP windows open. (Having multiple open simultaneously or even multiple connection dialogs prevents this process from working.)
2. Open your RDP window and let it open on the wrong monitor.
3. Move it to the monitor you want it to open to.
4. Maximize it in this monitor (this is critical!)
5. While the window is maximized, close the RDP window (be sure to exit out of the RDP application completely if you get bumped back to the connection dialog).
6. Rerun the RDP/mstsc application and try again. It should reopen in the window you last closed it in.

Comment: This is how it used to work prior to the creators update. Are you sure you're running windows 10 version 15063?

Comment: Yup. `15063.332` and I just tested it to make sure I wasn't mistaking it for pre-updated functionality.